# Accessing href attribute using invoke() in each() Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I am new to Cypress and I'm trying to access the href attribute for each div tag from a group using invoke() but it gives error.  Can someone suggest how you do it?

```
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile--mls').each(($el,index,$list) => {
            $el.get('a')
                .invoke('attr','href')
                .then(href => {
                    cy.request(href)
                        .its('status')
                        .should('eq',200)
                })
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `.get()` is appropriate - it only works from the `<body>` not from each `'.bms-scoreboard__game-tile--mls'`.

Try `.find()` instead

With jQuery operators

```js
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile--mls')
  .each(($el,index,$list) => {
    const href = $el.find('a').attr('href')
    cy.request(href)
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200)
  })
})
```

or with Cypress operators

```js
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile--mls')
  .each(($el,index,$list) => {
    cy.wrap($el).find('a')
      .invoke('attr','href')
      .then(href => {
        cy.request(href)
           .its('status')
           .should('eq',200)
      })
  })
})
```

or move "find" into first selector

```js
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile--mls a')
  .each($a => {
    const href = $a.attr('href')
    cy.request(href)
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$el` is a JQuery element, and not itself in the Cypress chain. You'll need to use `cy.wrap()` to use it in a Cypress chain.

```js
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile--mls').each(($el,index,$list) => {
            cy.wrap($el)
                .get('a')
                .invoke('attr','href')
                .then(href => {
                    cy.request(href)
                        .its('status')
                        .should('eq',200)
                })
        })
```